# Python запуск / остановка функции

Tags: python, многопоточность, время, sleep

есть цикл, как сделать чтобы можно было его запустить и остановить вводом /start и /stop

тот же input() замораживает скрипт

заранее спасибо

upd. допустим у меня есть функция

```
def foo(text):
    while True:
        print(text)
        time.sleep(1)
```

и мне допустим надо ее запустить несколько раз, например с текстом "text 1", "text 2" и "text 3" и они должны работать одновременно

upd2.

сделал такой код, но при старте перестает работать input()

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def foo(text):
    for i in range(10):
        out = text + ' [' + str(i) + ']'
        print(out)
        sleep(1)

#t1 = Thread(target=foo, args=('text 1',)) 

threads = []

while True:
    cmd = input('cmd > ')
    if cmd == 'start':
        text = input('text > ')
        threads.append(Thread(target=foo, args=(text,)))
        threads[-1].start()
        threads[-1].join()
    elif cmd == 'stop':
        pass
```

upd3. 
как тогда сделать чтобы код продолжил выполняться после запуска потока (чтобы 123 вывелось не в конце, а в начале)

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def foo(text):
    for i in range(10):
        out = text + ' [' + str(i) + ']'
        print(out)
        sleep(1)

t1 = Thread(target=foo, args=('text 1',))
t2 = Thread(target=foo, args=('text 2',))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

print('123')
```

Comment: Цикл "останавливает" поток, в котором запущен, следовательно вам нужно копать в сторону многопоточности.

Comment: Операции ввода-вывода блокирующие. К тому же, когда функция начинает печатать в консоль, Вы не можете ничего ввести, как Вы и сказали в UPD.

Comment: Вы знаете, что делает `t1.join()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую почитать о назначении метода `join()`. Предлагаю такое решение:

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def foo(text):
    for i in range(10):
        out = text + ' [' + str(i) + ']'
        print(out)
        sleep(1)

#t1 = Thread(target=foo, args=('text 1',)) 

threads = []

while True:
    cmd = input('cmd > ')
    if cmd == 'start':
        text = input('text > ')
        threads.append(Thread(target=foo, args=(text,)))
        threads[-1].start()
        #threads[-1].join()
    elif cmd == 'stop':
        pass

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Теперь ввод не будет блокироваться, однако, вместе с ожиданием ввода в консоль будет производиться вывод, что крайне неудобно. В связи с этим я ещё подредактировал Ваш код "на свой вкус":

```py
from threading import Thread
from threading import Lock
from time import sleep

lk = Lock() # Мьютекс

def foo(text):
    for i in range(10):
        out = text + ' [' + str(i) + ']'
        lk.acquire()
        print(out)
        lk.release()
        sleep(1)

#t1 = Thread(target=foo, args=('text 1',)) 

threads = []

while True:
    lk.acquire()
    cmd = input('cmd > ')
    lk.release()
    if cmd == 'start':
        lk.acquire()
        text = input('text > ')
        lk.release()
        threads.append(Thread(target=foo, args=(text,)))
        threads[-1].start()
        sleep(5) # Спит, чтобы функция успела хоть что-то вывести до очередной блокировки
        #threads[-1].join()
    elif cmd == 'stop':
        pass

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Здесь я устранил "борьбу" за право использования командной строки между потоками с помощью классического подхода – использования мьютексов. И добавил сон в функцию ввода, чтобы дать время поработать другим потокам.

Если всё-таки лень читать, объясню: `join()` сделана для того, чтобы **ждать** завершения работы потока. То есть, пока поток, к которому Вы присоединились (join – вступать, присоединяться), не завершит свою работу, дальше вызова `join()` Вы не уйдёте. Поэтому следует сначала запустить достаточное количество потоков, а потом дожидаться окончания работы их всех.

Также очень рекомендую почитать [это](http://python-3.ru/page/import-threading), [это](https://python-scripts.com/threading) и [это](https://dev-gang.ru/article/mnogopotocznost-v-python-t2bkyunvku/).